# Sorting by word count that store in dict python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, count

how can you sort by word count?
sorted() sort me only by the number of numbers? Thank you for your help

```
def make_dict(s):
    w_dict = {}
    word_list = s.split()
    for wrd in word_list:
        w_dict[wrd] = w_dict.get(wrd,0) +1
    return w_dict

print(make_dict("test is test"))
```

input is `print(make_dict("test is test tests tests tests"))`
output is `{'test': 2, 'is': 1, 'tests': 3}`

im search output `tests ,test ,is`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code like approach_1 or use `collections.Counter` like approach_2.

1. You can `sorted` on `dict.items()` and return result as `dict`
2. Use `Counter` and return `most_common`.

**Approach_1**

```
def make_dict(s):
    w_dict = {}
    word_list = s.split()
    for wrd in word_list:
        w_dict[wrd] = w_dict.get(wrd,0) +1
    return dict(sorted(w_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

print(make_dict("test is test tests tests tests"))
# {'tests': 3, 'test': 2, 'is': 1}
```

**Approach_2**

```
from collections import Counter
def make_dict_2(s):
    word_list = s.split()
    c = Counter(word_list)
    return dict(c.most_common())

print(make_dict_2("test is test tests tests tests"))
#{'tests': 3, 'test': 2, 'is': 1}
```